# Can we use electron.nativeImage APIs in a NodeJS worker thread?

Tags: node.js, electron, node-worker-threads

Is it possible to use `electron` APIs from within a NodeJS worker thread spawned from the main Electron process? We have attempted to use Electron's [nativeImage](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/native-image) module from within a worker thread (Node worker, not web worker) yet `nativeImage` is always `undefined`. Our worker:

```
const { parentPort } = require("worker_threads");
const { nativeImage } = require("electron");

parentPort.on("message", message => {
    if (nativeImage === undefined) {
        parentPort.postMessage("nativeImage is undefined!");
    }
    let image = nativeImage.createEmpty();  // fails
});
```

The main thread which creates this worker receives the `"nativeImage is undefined!"` message.